# How can I find the page description contained in the meta tag of a given url (if it has a description)?

Tags: javascript, meta-tags

I am trying to develop a website where I post some links along with a brief description about them. I would like to *use JavaScript to find the description of a given url using the url's meta tag if it has one.* I tried to search for a solution but found all kinds of related questions and answers I can't figure out. Can someone please provide a simple explanation, or a link or anything really to help me out? I'm a newbie and I'm sorry if this is a stupid question or has already been answered.

For example, if had to post a link of wired.com on my page, I would like the description of wired.com to be automatically obtained from Wired's page meta tag. Like this:

**Wired.com | "Get in-depth coverage of current and future trends in technology, and how they are shaping business, entertainment, communications, science, politics, and culture at Wired.com."**

The description part after the "|" should be retrieved by a script.

I just copy pasted this from Wired's description meta tag but want to automate the whole process. Any suggestions would be very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: We're going to need a bit more information. Are you trying to get the meta tag of the page you're currently on? Or are you trying to get the meta tag of a page you're linking to?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Adrain! I'm trying to get the meta tag of the page I am linking to. For example, if had to post the link of wired.com on my page, I would like to description of wired.com to be automatically obtained from Wired's page meta tag. Like this: Wired.com | "Get in-depth coverage of current and future trends in technology, and how they are shaping business, entertainment, communications, science, politics, and culture at Wired.com."

Comment: You'll need a server-side programming language to assist with this, as you won't be able to access arbitrary web sites through JS. You want to look at Ajax to fetch a server-side result "live" without reloading the page

Answer (score 0):

You can't make cross-domain requests if that site (wired.com) doesn't provide jsonp API or doesn't allow cross origin requests via `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` HTTP header. More details about CORS - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Wow. It seems I have a long way to go. Thanks a lot Serjio!